# Shader and opengl transformations

Tags: opengl, shader, cg

When i add shaders (in cg) to my opengl program all the local transformations (glRotatef, glTranslatef and glScalef between glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix) stop working. Transforms outside push/pop still working though. So what might be the problem here?

update:
I have a rotating cube in the center of the scene:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
drawBox();
glPopMatrix();
```

and after that i send worldview and worldviewprojection matrices to shader:

```
cgGLSetStateMatrixParameter(
    myCgVertexParam_modelViewProj,
    CG_GL_MODELVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX,
    CG_GL_MATRIX_IDENTITY
);

cgGLSetStateMatrixParameter(
    myCgVertexParam_modelView,
    CG_GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,
    CG_GL_MATRIX_IDENTITY
);
```

Vertex shader code:

```
void C9E2v_fog(float4 position    : POSITION,
               float4 color       : COLOR,

            out float4 oPosition    : POSITION,
            out float4 oColor       : COLOR,
            out float  fogExponent  : TEXCOORD1,

        uniform float    fogDensity,  // Based on log2
        uniform float4x4 modelViewProj : MODELVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX,
        uniform float4x4 modelView : MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
{   
  // Assume nonprojective modelview matrix
  float3 eyePosition = mul(modelView, position).xyz;
  float fogDistance  = length(eyePosition);
  fogExponent  = fogDistance * fogDensity;
  oPosition    = mul(modelViewProj, position);

  //oDecalCoords = decalCoords;
  oColor       = color;
}
```

So in the end cube doesnt rotate, but if i do write (no push/pop)

```
glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
drawBox();
```

everything works fine. How do i fix that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "stop working"? Specify expected output and actual output... Some sample code would not be amiss either.

Comment: i updated the main post, please check it

Answer (score 3):

You can use either fixed function pipeline or programmable one. Since you switched to shaders, fixed function pipeline "stopped working". To switch back you need to `glUseProgram(0)`. And you need to send those local transformations to the shader.

Comment: how i can send transformations to shader? and i updated the main post

Comment: @spacevillain: in your case you need to send `modelViewProj` and `modelView` by hand, take a look at this code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740905/what-is-gl-modelviewmatrix-and-gl-modelviewprojectionmatrix-in-modern-opengl/3741453#3741453