# Drawing texture on Polygon Shape

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am drawing some polygon shapes and  trying to draw textures on it.

```
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.set(new Vector2[]{
        new Vector2(0, 0)
        , new Vector2(x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
        , new Vector2(x1 - x2, y1 - y2 - p)
        , new Vector2(0, 0 - p)});


        float[] vertices = new float[]{
        0,
        0,
        (x1 - x2) * Constants.PPM ,
        (y1 - y2) * Constants.PPM ,
        (x1 - x2) * Constants.PPM,
        (y1 - y2 - p) * Constants.PPM,
        0,
        (0 - p) * Constants.PPM };

        EarClippingTriangulator triangulator = new EarClippingTriangulator();
        ShortArray triangleIndices = triangulator.computeTriangles(vertices);
        PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(texture), vertices, triangleIndices.toArray());
        PolygonSprite poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
        poly.setPosition(posOffset, tmpBody.getPosition().y);
       // polySprites.add(poly);
```

in draw() method,

```
poly.draw(polyBatch);
```

The problem: 
The polygon shape varies in length but the width is constant. I am trying to fill the polygonshape with a texture but not able to fill/stretch it properly to the size and shape.

Not sure if I am describing it well, so here's an image detailing what I am trying to achieve. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the 'polygons' are still quads. So we don't need to complicate things here.

All there's to do is to set rotation and translation transformations to the sprites and/or the container polygon.

Read more here: [OpenGL Transformation matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740905/what-is-gl-modelviewmatrix-and-gl-modelviewprojectionmatrix-in-modern-opengl/3741453#3741453)
It's not exactly what you'll need to implement. But I hope you get the gist.

It can look something like the following depending on how your implementation of `PolySprite` is:

```
PolygonSprite poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
poly.setPosition(posOffset, tmpBody.getPosition().y); //
poly.setRotation(slope);
PolySprites.add(poly);
```

Comment: How do I repeat the image/texture to fill the shape?

Comment: Draw it multiple times, every time with a different transformation. You may have to calculate the no. of repetitions depending on the size of the container and each sprite.